# Get groups where values go from 0 to 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to get all the users from a dataframe where a specific column goes from `1` to `0`.

For example, with the following dataframe I want to keep only user 1 and 2 as their values go from `1` to `0`.

*Relevant rows*

- Row 6 to 7 for user 1
- Row 9 to 10 for user 2

```
    user  value
0      0      0
1      0      0
2      0      1
3      0      1
4      1      0
5      1      1
6      1      1
7      1      0
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     2      0
11     2      0
```

Desired Result

```
    user  value
4      1      0
5      1      1
6      1      1
7      1      0
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     2      0
11     2      0
```

I have tried window functions and conditions but for some reason I cannot get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `cummax`

```
df.loc[df.user.isin(df.loc[df.value != df.groupby('user')['value'].cummax(),'user'])]
Out[769]: 
    user  value
4      1      0
5      1      1
6      1      1
7      1      0
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     2      0
11     2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to check if the next value is `1` (`df.value.shift(1).eq(1)`), and combine that with a mask checking if the current value is `0` (`df.value.eq(0)`). Then, group by `'user'` and `transform('any')` to create the appropriate mask:

```
filtered = df[(df.value.eq(0) & df.value.shift(1).eq(1)).groupby(df.user).transform('any')]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
    user  value
4      1      0
5      1      1
6      1      1
7      1      0
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     2      0
11     2      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy.filter`. If any `diff` (difference of successive values) is equal to **-1** (0-1), keep the group.

```
df.groupby('user').filter(lambda g: g['value'].diff().eq(-1).any())
```

*NB. this assumes you only have 0 and 1s, if you can have other numbers you also need to use two conditions: `(g['value'].eq(1)&g['value'].shift(-1).eq(0)).any()`*

output:

```
    user  value
4      1      0
5      1      1
6      1      1
7      1      0
8      2      1
9      2      1
10     2      0
11     2      0
```